# I have tried to use accordion of bootsrap 5 in angular 17 with ngFor and I have a problem

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, accordion

```
<div class="accordion w-50 mx-auto" id="accordionExample">
  <div *ngFor="let note of notes; index as i;">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne ">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="'#collapse + i'" aria-expanded="true" >
        {{note.subject}}

      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="'collapse + i'" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        {{note.text}}
        <div class="mt-2">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button">Edit</button>
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger ms-3" type="button">Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

I want to open one accordion for each element but all elements open. I use different id with index but it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your problem you should change your code like this:

```
<div class="accordion w-50 mx-auto" id="accordionExample">
  <div *ngFor="let note of notes; index as i;">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne ">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-bs-target]="'#collapse' + i" aria-expanded="true" >
        {{note.subject}}

      </button>
    </h2>
    <div [id]="'collapse' + i" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        {{note.text}}
        <div class="mt-2">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button">Edit</button>
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger ms-3" type="button">Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Using the Angular data binding property you can set the ids correctly

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check the below link in angular 17 + bootstrap 5 and I hope this will solve your issue.

**Below code is making dynamic accordions:**

```
<div class="accordion-item" *ngFor="let item of selectedData; let i = index">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" [id]="'heading'+i">
     
        <button class="accordion-button" [ngClass]="{ 'collapsed': i != 0 }" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-bs-target]="'#collapse'+i" aria-expanded="true" [attr.aria-controls]="'collapse'+i">
          Accordion Item {{i}}
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div [id]="'collapse'+i" class="accordion-collapse collapse" [ngClass]="{ 'show': i == 0 }" [attr.aria-labelledby]="'heading'+i" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[use accordion of bootsrap 5 in angular 17 with ngFor](https://therichpost.com/angular-12-bootstrap-5-accordion-with-dynamic-data/)